# My navigation link isn't connecting OutSystems

Tags: outsystems

I'm trying to link my web pages and the navigation isn't working. I've set the destination as my Rosters Page. Outsystems seems to even tell me what data type I need but when I put that into the expression editor it gives me the below message. I think I may have set the structure up wrong. I just can't understand why I can't input the TeamID attribute in to retrieve my Rosters page on the next screen. I mean, TeamID is even an attribute on the Rosters table itself. So why does it not seem to link?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the print screen I can see that the TeamRosters page input is probably a structure. You should change it to be a LongInteger, as far as I can understand from the screen.

Comment: Thank you! I'm starting to understand this whole OutSytems a bit more now! It feels so good! YES! DX